# Accessing the body using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a homescreen.jsp. On click of a link i open an iFrame. Now when this iFrame opens i need to hide the homescreen.jsp vertical scrollbar.

I am trying to access the body of homescreen.jsp using jquery. I got to access it very easily, but I landed in an issue when I was trying multiple browsers.

```
$('body,html').css('overflow','hidden')
```

This works just fine in IE. But It does not work in Firefox properly. The new screen which opens moves completely to the right side.

Comment: Try giving the body an ID, and accessing them on separate lines. I don't know how to handle jQuery multi-selectors, but I'm pretty sure IDs would work cross-browser. Also, you don't have a semi-colon... :)

(just thoughts)

Answer (score 0):

The issue won't be the one you're mentioning!

And also, note that you need to write code that would work for each browser! Sometimes you need to write code that works on Chrome and a code that would work on Firefox; all seperately.

However, the movement to the right is because the content is clipped to the window. And all the content that is exceeding is removed from the document; is not shown.

Learn more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow